# How to correctly remove merge commit after pull? (handling detached HEAD)

Tags: git

Here's the case:

1. I've made a couple of `commit`s to local master
2. I tried to `push` and found there are some new commits in remote repo
3. I've `pull`ed the new commits (no conlicts, merged via the recursive strategy)

The result is the extra "merge" commit. I wanted to get rid of it and learned about the `git pull --rebase` command. My idea was to do the following:

1. (see `git reflog` and) use `git checkout HEAD@{1}` to get to the previous state
2. `git pull --rebase` to merge "correctly"
3. `git push` the result

The problem is after `git checkout HEAD@{1}` I got into the "detached HEAD" state, and `git pull --rebase` haven't actually modified master, so `git push` resulted with the unwanted merge commit in the remote repo.

How could I "fix" the unwanted merge commit (given there's no conflict with remote edits)? Ideally, I'm looking for a set of commands that will be the same for 2 and 22 new commits (that's why I looked into `git checkout HEAD@{1}`, it basically says "go to the prev state"); in other words, what I'm looking for is probably how to tell git "no, this is not detached HEAD, I want this to be the new master".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted was `reset`, not `checkout`. Okay, so you've gone rather a long way down the wrong road; how will you get out of it?

1. First checkout the current branch to get out of the detached head state.
2. Then, using your knowledge (from the `reflog`) of the SHA of the commit before the merge commit, `git reset --hard <SHA>` to get back to before the merge commit and erase it.
3. That's it! Now start over with the `git pull --rebase` that you wanted in the first place.

[Extra free advice: Don't `git pull`. Instead, `git fetch` and then *look* at the remote tracking branch and the local branch and think about how you want to "combine" them. You can do it with `merge` or with `rebase`. If you say `git merge --no-ff` you can ensure that no unwanted "merge commit" will be created.]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset your branch to a specific commit id

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
git pull --rebease
```